# Two consecutive pseudo selectors in jQuery don't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have some issues selecting an element with jQuery.

my HTML code comes down to:

```
<body>
  <p>Dont mind me, sir</p>
  <p>Select me please!</p>
  <p class="fabulous">So fab</p>
</body>
```

with some jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p:not(.fabulous):last-child').css({'background':'yellow'});
});
```

With the selector `$('p:not(.fabulous):last-child')` I am trying to select the last element of its parent (body, in this case) that does not have class "fabulous". With `$('p:not(.fabulous)')` I select all non-fabulous children of `body` but why can I not select the last child of the leftover `p` elements? I'd very much appreciate an answer concerning the behaviour of `:last-child` and `:not(`, or whatever selector I misunderstood.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) instead of [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/).

Comment: Isn't `:last` a jQuery extension? Because I'd like to do it without extensions...

Comment: What's wrong with "extensions"?  Are you that worried about DOM performance?

Comment: P.S. `:not` is implemented as a "jQuery extension".  Check `jQuery.expr[':']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last-child` selects all elements that are the *last child* of their *parent*.  The last (`<p>`) child of the `<body>` is `<p class="fabulous">`.

So, when you do `p:not(.fabulous):last-child`, you are asking for a `<p>` that is *both* the last child of its parent **and** doesn't have the class `fabulous`.  No such element exists.

You'd need to use `$('p:not(.fabulous):last')` in this case.

Comment: Choosing this as best answer because of it's explaination - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `$('p:not(.fabulous):last').css({'background-color':'yellow'});` or `$('p:not(.fabulous)').last().css({'background-color':'yellow'});` instead